# Retrieve Google Forms (Questions) Data as JSON using REST API

Tags: google-forms, google-forms-api

If a google form is publicm then why can't I retrieve the data as a JSON from

[https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/{formID}](https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/%7BformID%7D)

using the REST API ?

https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/get

Comment: Hi there @anjanesh! Could you please clarify why you can retrieve the API data? Do you receive any errors/warnings? Do you have permissions over the Form?

Comment: I want to achieve the same thing that's possible with a public gsheet. For example, this gets a JSON representation of my public sheet - `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zwblTR5DWzgOiVxsDYJJkP5Gcmi4OGiCtldI0nyxZGo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=0` - I want the form equivalent. Like `docs.google.com/forms/d/{formID}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=0`